# Plot with black dots on the top of the boxplot

Tags: r

I am making box plots with ggplot2. On the top of each box are 1 or more black dots. They only appear if the box has some outliers. I don't know how can I get rid of them.

See image below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outlier.shape = NA` argument of the function `geom_boxplot` to hide the outliers.
*Note: you do not provide a reproducible example and do not tell what packages you are using. Based on the picture I guess you are using the package `ggplot2`*. `iris` is a base R dataset so the example below is reproducible.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# with outliers
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Width))
```

[image]

```r
# hide outliers
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = iris, aes(y = Sepal.Width), outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>